# Why 'another' instead of 'the other'?

Tags: meaning, usage

If there are two genes that are different by only a single base pair, and a single point mutation happens, why could one be converted into ***another***, not ***the other***? Does the author mean a new, different third gene?

> Generally speaking, a single mutation in an existing gene cannot
> produce a new gene with a different function. If two genes differ by
> only a single base pair, then a single point mutation could convert
> one into ***another***. Usually, however, these two genes will be
> regarded merely as variants of the same gene, and will have an
> identical function unless the mutation is at some critical spot that
> renders the second gene non-functional. The same goes for other basic
> alterations, such as the deletion or repetition of an existing
> sequence. To get a gene with an entirely new function usually requires
> many, many alterations, a concatenation of several unlikely steps — a
> series of just the right mutations happening either all at once, or
> one after another. Unlikelihood multiplies into impossibility. If I
> guess the next card you draw from the deck, you’d be impressed but not
> amazed. If I guessed ten in a row, you’d suspect a trick because that
> would happen only about once every fifty quadrillion trials.

[The Ascent of Humanity](https://ascentofhumanity.com/text/chapter-6-08/)

Comment: I think "the other" would in fact be better here.

Comment: I can only agree with @EthanBolker that this appears to be an unfortunate word choice.

Answer (score 0):

Q. **If there are two genes that are different by only a single base pair, and a single point mutation happens, why could one be converted into another**, not the other? **Does the author mean a new, different third gene?**

Yes I believe you are correct. It is a different gene

---

This not my specialist subject but I believe another is being used as a pronoun and the Antecedent is “**gene that only differs by a single base pair**”

If two genes differ by only a single base pair, then a single point mutation could convert one into a ***different*** “**gene that only differs by a single base pair**”.

My reasoning for this is that the text specifically states **"a single point mutation**" (not just any mutation), which I am guessing would lead to a variation of a **"single base pair"**

---

However later in the text another is not used as a pronoun. "or one after another" could be replaced by "or one after an other"

---

Q. **Why 'another' instead of 'the other'**?

**Another can be used as a pronoun** whilst I find no reference to other being a pronoun in this context.

**another** determiner, **pronoun (DIFFERENT)** **a different person or thing**:

Ref CED [**Another**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/another)

Ref Grammar Revolution [**What is a pronoun**](https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/what-is-a-pronoun.html)